# Cannot install Flex (lexical analyser) on Windows, unable to find comprehensive instructions

Tags: command-line, flex-lexer

I'm taking a class on Flex/Bison at University this semester, and I'm having serious issues trying to get Flex working. (Possibly due to my own inaptitude, but I'm finding a solution very, very difficult to research)

I am trying to use the Command Prompt to navigate to a file containing a .l (Lex) file and then use Flex to generate a .yy file `flex -ooutputfile.yy.c inputfile.l`

- I downloaded the windows version of Flex from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/flex.htm
- I checked to make sure I had the appropriate .dlls (as mentioned in the installation instructions here http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/install.html)
- I downloaded Visual Studio 2008 via Dreamspark and installed it (from which point on I used Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt)
- I installed Cygwin at someone's suggestion
- I installed Perl after noticing the Requirements (as mentioned here http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/install.html) list 'perl, etc.'

After each and every attempt at a solution I continue to receive the message `'flex' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I've spent several hours searching however I am at a loss. I've been unable to find any comprehensive instructions on how to install Flex or on it's requirements / dependencies... Any help would be much appreciated!

- I added C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin to the PATH environment variables, System Variables. I am still getting the same error. (The location where flex.exe is located)

Comment: Open a command window and type `path`; this will show you the contents of the path variable. Is `C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin` in that list?

Comment: It's still not working though, I'm afraid.

Comment: Okay, so the path is correct (and I assume you've checked that flex.exe is actually in that directory). Now type `flex --version`. If it still doesn't work, the file must be damaged and I would try reinstalling it.

Comment: I discovered the problem! The PATH was, effectively... 

C:\Ruby; C:\Flex 

This meant the path displayed when I looked for contents of the path variable, but did not actually work, changing it to (effectively) - 

C:\Ruby;C:\Flex 

- fixed the problem immediately!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are getting means that `flex.exe` isn't in your `PATH` environment variable.  You need to figure out where the installer installed `flex` and add that to your `PATH` or manually install it somewhere in your `PATH`

Comment: Thank you! How can I add something to my PATH?

Comment: (I found this tutorial on how to add the PATH variable http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/command_line.shtml - it refers to Python, however I did the same thing for flex.exe and added that directory to the PATH. It still does not work!)

Comment: @ShimmerGeek: I did exactly the same and it really doesn't work. Did you managed to do it?

Answer (score 1):

you can use flex&bison under windows without any external dependencies at http://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/. No need GnuWin32, perl or visual studio at all.

Comment: Another application needs flex available in the command line. If i understand it right then i only receive **win_flex** as command with this installation after adding the installation folder to PATH. Is there an option to map the command? Or should i place an short-cut with name flex.exe into the same folder referring to win_flex.exe?